# Set ID item listview from database

Tags: android-listview

I need to display a list of events in a listview, I want to do is that the ID of an item of listview is the ID that is registered in my DB. It is posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you create a custom list adapter that takes in a custom object modeled around your database.

Do some research on BaseAdapter.

Once you've created your custom list adapter you can store all your database rows into something like

```
ArrayList<CustomObject> co = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

Then when an OnClickListener is fired you can use the position like so:

```
int id = co.get(position).getId();
```

Assuming of course your CustomObject has a method called getId().